# Import Css dynamically through an API in Angular

Tags: css, angular, api, sass, cdn

I want to import a CSS dynamically from cloud storage.

in `styles.scss` I want something like @import var(--url)

Is it possible or is there an alternative?

Why?

I want to import some different CSS according to the different user logins.

Comment: You can, where are trying to do it? Sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I have created a link tag in the index.html file and assigned it an id.

Now when I want to apply it, I have applied it using the `setAttribute function`

```
this.document.getElementById('id1')!.setAttribute('href', ${styleUrlFromAPI});
```